# How to install Canon Pixma MP620?

Tags: software-installation

I have been trying to install my Canon Pixma MP620 printer via cable network on my Ubuntu 13.04 64bit OS for two days. Previously I also tried to install the printer on Linux Mint 15, but failed.

There are lots (really tons) of well written tutorials how to install the printer (e.g. this [wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Canon-Drucker) on ubuntuusers.de). However nothing seems to work.

After messing up my system with lots of packages and different drivers I did a complete reinstall of the operating system.

Comment: If I try to add the printer via the direct device URI: cnijnet:/<PRINTERS-MAC-ADDRESS>, I get this error: "CUPS server error: There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'client-error-not-possible'."

Comment: maybe this thread will help? http://cloudnull.io/2011/05/mp-620-630-debian-based-univeral-installer/ good luck. the mp620 is plain horror, I know!

Comment: The universa-installer failed on Ubuntu 14.04 64bits. I just contacted the author, just in case there is an update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have an MP620 printer that stopped working on Ubuntu 13.04.
After some investigations I found out that CUPS did not have suport for BJNP.
I tried to install the support with

```
sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp
```

After this, CUPS found the printer and the driver automatically.

before installing `cups-backend-bjnp` I followed the instructions from this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140916005552/http://linuxg.net/how-to-setup-install-canon-inkjet-pixma-ip1300-canon-inkjet-pixma-ip1600-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04).

Comment: Awesome. Just installed the printer on Ubuntu 14.04. They only thing I had to do, was to install cups-backend-bjnp. After that I could add the printer and print via my local area network.

Comment: Do you have the scanner working with wifi?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the printer working on my 64bit machines running 13.10 by installing cups-backend-bjnp

```
sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp
```

Then open printers, click on add printer.
Select Enter URI, then enter the device URI (i.e. "bjnp://192.168.1.10")
Click next
Select Canon from the listbox.
Click forward
Select PIXMA MP620 from the models listbox
Click forward
Add any descriptions you like then hit Apply and try to print a test page.

I recommend setting your router to provide the printer a static ip address so that you won't have to re-add the printer every time your router resets.