# How to install a printer&scanner Canon MP630

Tags: drivers, software-installation

As a newcomer to Ubuntu (version 14.04 LTS) and not being a computer expert I try to connect my printer/scanner Canon Pixma MP630.
I added it in system settings Printer and now I can print from the computer but do not get info e.g. for ink status, and I cannot scan to the computer.
I have not found the word scanner in system settings.

Then, I have downloaded the actual Canon driver software from their homepage, then downloaded and installed libcupsys2 from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/libcupsys2-dev/1.4.0-3.
Then all attempts to install the Canon stuff failed for not fullfillible dependencies with the comment libcupsys2 (>=1.2.1).

Then, I followed the recommendation from [How to install Canon Pixma MP620?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320800/how-to-install-canon-pixma-mp620) and entered into the terminal: sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp
 but did not see any change.

Can anyone advise what to try next in order to get full functionality for printing and scanning?

Comment: Trusty with Karmic drivers? And, are you sure you followed http://askubuntu.com/a/355704/169736? Why you need to install "libcupsys2"?

Comment: Small rant: downvote without comment is not what I consider helpful (and we are here to help people). moma: I would suggest to stop using turorials that are not designed for the system you are using. Karmic is pretty old ;) I know it might be daunting but this: http://askubuntu.com/a/464334/15811 seems to be new enough.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the help. I tried to follow  askubuntu.com/a/464334/15811 but was stopped by an 404 error after entering wget http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0100004596. So, I have a problem how to continue. Any idea?